# How do I create a Treemap and depict it through flex?

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, flash-builder, implementation, treemap

So basically what I'm trying to do is make something like this:
http://store.kapit.biz/demo/treemap/prod/index.html#

I've searched long and hard to find a site that would show me some pseudocode (at least) or an algorithm as to how to implement this type of application. But everything I find are only applications that take in data and do all the work for me to create the graph. I need to actually create it for myself, just a simple one for now. Does anyone know where I can find this? What I want it to do is take data from a database and use it to create the treemap, then express it in a GUI like in the link above. If any specifics are needed I can provide it. I'm trying to do this in Flash Builder using Flex and using ColdFusion as the backend. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check this out](http://www.axiis.org/examples/TreemapExample.html)

[Axiis](http://www.axiis.org/) is a open source library based on [Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/) that enables you to make complex data visualizations.

Cheers